# Verify uniqueness of a value in a column in CouchDB cradle

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I have a CouchDb table for cookies with ids and access tokens. I want to create a new cookie for a given token, only if that token doesn't already exist in our table. How could I do that in CouchDb with cradle for nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

I read the cookie first and if it was there i would merge otherwise I would create a new one.